# DelayedJob: Deserializing ActiveRecord objects throws SerializationTypeMistmatch error on serializeable fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, delayed-job

Having a strage serialization error when working with DelayedJob. Say I have the following ActiveRecord class User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :metadata, UserMetaData
end
```

And UserMetaData looks like this:

```
class UserMetaData < Hash
  def some_function
    #do work
  end
end
```

If my DelayedJob does this internally:

```
class MyJob
  attr_accessor :user_id

  def initialize(user_id)
    self.user_id = user_id
  end

  def perform
    @user = User.find(self.user_id)
  end
end
```

Whenever I run it, I get the following error locally:

```
[Worker(host:home pid:87197)] MyJob failed with ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: Attribute was supposed to be a UserMetaData, but was a Hash - 2 failed attempts
```

It works fine outside of the DelayedJob system. It appears that whenever it fetches a record from the database, it doesn't deserialize it correctly. I did notice that if I change my User class to:

```
serialize :metadata, Hash
```

It works fine, but comes out as a Hash in DelayedJob and a UserMetaData outside of the DelayedJob system. The problem here is that I cannot use functions on the UserMetaData class (ie: @user.metadata.some_function) when I'm in the DelayedJob system. Not quite sure what to make of it. Any pointers would be really helpful.

Update: There appears to be an open ticket on Github related to this issue too: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/300.

Thanks!